# How to do the square root in PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: math, vba, powerpoint, square-root

Here is some math code that adds A to B:

```
Sub math()
    A = 23
    B = 2
    ABSumTotal = A + B
    strMsg = "The answer is " & "$" & ABSumTotal & "."
    MsgBox strMsg
End Sub
```

But how can I calculate a square root of ABSumTotal?
Is it possible in PowerPoint VBA?

Comment: Are you seriously trying to compute a square root in PowerPoint macros/VBA? Why do you need to do that in the first place? (Not mocking, just very curious.)

Comment: it's just that I want to move some shapes along an ellipse orbit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use: Sqr()

```
strMsg = "The answer is " & "$" & Sqr(ABSumTotal) & "."
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the function Sqr?

See: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2h9y284%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `^` to compute `X^(1/2)`

Edit: added parenthesis

Comment: I misreaded the question and answered for cubic root and made a correction afterwards. But I dont think x^1/2 is less readable than sqr(x) which looks like square to much to me :)

Comment: Doesn't exponentiation take precedence over division?  If so, you'd need x^(1/2).